# Splitting an MS Word File using Excel VBA - referencing section ranges

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Hopefully a quick one.

I through together a macro for splitting a word file (merged file of letters) into individual pdfs and naming them based on a ref number included in the file.

```
 'Start split
For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections

    Set rng = sec.Range  'Range of section
    SecText = sec.Range.Text 'All text within section
    SecTextPosition = InStr(SecText, "Our ref: ")  'Position of "Out ref: " within the section
    strCDRS = Mid(SecText, (SecTextPosition + 9), 16)  'Retrieved CDRS reference

    If sec.Index < ActiveDocument.Sections.Count Then
        rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 'drop trailing section break
    End If
        rng.ExportAsFixedFormat strFolder & "\" & Replace(strCDRS, "/", "-") & "-" & strLetterType & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF

    Set rng = Nothing
Next sec
```

This works perfectly **when embedded in the word file**.  However, when embedding in the excel file and referencing the document, I get a type mismatch on the:

```
        Set rng = sec.Range  'Range of section
```

Look at the value of sec.Range, it looks fine, so it appears to be something to do with the rng range object.  Am I missing something obvious?

Full draft code as follows:

```
Sub SplitExport()
Dim sec As Section
Dim rng As Range
Dim strSplitFile As String
Dim strCDRS As String
Dim strLetterType As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim SecText As String
Dim SecTextPosition As Long
Dim strfldr As FileDialog
Dim strfile As FileDialog
Dim WordFile As Word.Document

'Set word application
  Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")

'Pick file to split

Set strfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With strfile
    .Title = "Select a file to split"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    strSplitFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

'Check if a file was selected
If strSplitFile = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot proceed without file selection", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Set Letter Type String
strLetterType = InputBox("Please enter letter code...")
If strLetterType = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot proceed without letter code", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Set folder to save PDFs to

Set strfldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With strfldr
    .Title = "Select a folder to save split files"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'Check a folder was selected
If strFolder = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot proceed without folder selection", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Open file to split
Set WordFile = wordapp.Documents.Open(strSplitFile)
WordFile.Activate

'Start split
For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections

    Set rng = sec.Range  'Range of section
    SecText = sec.Range.Text 'All text within section
    SecTextPosition = InStr(SecText, "Our ref: ")  'Position of "Out ref: " within the section
    strCDRS = Mid(SecText, (SecTextPosition + 9), 16)  'Retrieved reference

    If sec.Index < ActiveDocument.Sections.Count Then
        rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 'drop trailing section break
    End If
        rng.ExportAsFixedFormat strFolder & "\" & Replace(strCDRS, "/", "-") & "-" & strLetterType & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF

    Set rng = Nothing
Next sec
```

End Sub

Comment: You need to define `rng` as a `Word.Range` (if using early binding) or as an `Object` (if using late binding, which you are) or else it will be defined as an `Excel.Range`.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for wasting anyone's time reading this - I haven't changed the reference from section to Word.section, etc.

I will leave up as a testament to my muppetry.